# Dynamic chart formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges, dynamic-chart-series

I'm having major problems with a dynamic chart.

I have two pivot tables where one is a "compare" and the other is todays live values.
Because the timestamps does not match up I use a vlookup to make them match.

[image]

As you can see the values in the pivots are unsynced and the C column has the vlookup to make sure they are in sync.

What I now want is to get a dynamic range chart which displays the values from when values are > 0 in column B (B18) and to the last row of column B.

What I have done so far is a index and match formula that finds the value 25 because it's not 0 and matches the end of the table with `= ""`

This is the formula for column A:

```
=INDEX(A5:A148;MATCH(INDEX(B5:B148;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B5:B148<>0;);0));B5:B148;0))
:INDEX(A5:A148;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B5:B148="";);0)-1)
```

If I select the formula and press F9 I see this:
[image]
It starts with "25.2" and ends with three zeros which is correct.
I use the same formula but with different return column for column B and C, and they too return the correct values.

I paste these formulas in the name manager and when I select the formula I can see that it selects the correct range.

All good, right?

I try to add them in the chart and I get an error message:

> There is a problem with one or more of the formula references in the sheet.
>   Make sure the cell references, [unsure of the translation], named ranges and links to other workbooks in the formula is correct.

[image]

EDIT: Excel 365 if that makes any difference.

EDIT2:
The exact formula is:

```
=INDEX(Blad2!A5:A148;PASSA(INDEX(Blad2!B5:B148;PASSA(SANT;INDEX(Blad2!B5:B148<>0;);0));Blad2!B5:B148;0)):INDEX(Blad2!A5:A148;PASSA(SANT;INDEX(Blad2!B5:B148="";);0)-1)
```

Comment: can you post the EXACT formula you put into Name Manager? Copy and paste?

Comment: @Andreas I'm pretty sure, your problem is not locking the reference in your formula with $.

Comment: That's my feeling, too. If you use relative references in named ranges, they will be relative to the current cell position. That can be exploited in charting, but you probably hardly ever want that.

Comment: Oh my... I did not know that. Thank you both!

Comment: BTW, how is your formula different from `=INDEX(A5:A148,MATCH(TRUE,B5:B148<>0,0)):INDEX(A5:A148,MATCH(TRUE,B5:B148="",0)-1)`? Or `=OFFSET($A$5,MATCH(TRUE,B5:B148<>0,0)-1,0,MATCH(TRUE,B5:B148="",0)-MATCH(TRUE,B5:B148<>0,0),1)`?

Comment: @z32a7ul It seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use relative cell references in range name formulas, these will be relative to the position of the current cell.

If the current cell is in row 100 when the range is defined, and it uses references to row 1, then change the cell selection to row 99,  the range formula reference will point to row 1048576 and that may cause an error.

You may want to use absolute cell references instead.